# umbraco - site images

Tags: umbraco, templating

I have a static site with the structure

```
index.html
-css
-img
-js
```

Simple question how do I get the js and img folders into the umbraco structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you're using Umbraco 4 or 5.

For the purposes of this I'll assume Umbraco 4.

If you would like the JS files editable in the backend of umbracoyou'll need to add them to the scripts folder. Again at the root of the website. If you don't want them editable and want to keep them in the js folder, just copy the folder to the root of the site and then update the umbracoReserverdPaths entry in the web.config to include js:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/fonts,~/js" />
```

The same principal applied for the img folder in that you can add this to the umbracoReservedPaths in the web.config:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/fonts,~/js,~/img" />
```

If you want to have the images in "/img" editable in the media section of Umbraco you'll need to import them to the media library.

This is pretty easy, use the desktop media uploader (which can be downloaded from the media section) and just upload all the images from the img folder.

I hope this helps

T